# Rspec test attribute assignment during test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In Rails I want to test a workflow in which a model has the status `idle`, then gets assigned a `status` `running` and after the workflow is finished, the status is set to `idle`.

It is easy to check whether the status is set to `idle` with Rspec but I have no opportunity to check whether its status was set to `running` during the workflow execution.

My first thoughts were to use `has_changed?` but this is faulty as the status would also be changed after workflow execution.
I also considered `receive` but I do not understand the syntax to use there.

Checking a change of the model:

```
expect{ SomeTrigger }.to change { Workflow.status }.from('a').to('b')
```

Checking if attribute has different value than before:

```
expect{ Workflow.status_changed? }.to be_truthy
```

Is there a way in Rspec to check whether a model received specific attributes and values during its lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
expect { SomeTrigger }.to change { Workflow.status }.from('a').to('b')
```

More reading: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change

Where the example they give is:

```
class Counter
  class << self
    def increment
      @count ||= 0
      @count += 1
    end

    def count
      @count ||= 0
    end
  end
end

describe Counter, "#increment" do
  it "should not increment the count by 2" do
    expect{Counter.increment}.to_not change{Counter.count}.from(0).to(2)
  end

  # deliberate failure
  it "should not increment the count by 1" do
    expect{Counter.increment}.to_not change{Counter.count}.by(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes I know this technique. But in my example the Workflow starts with status `idle` is then changed during execution to status `running` and after it finished, its set to `idle` again. That said I could not check a status change from `idle` to `running` because the status is reset back to `idle`

Comment: I think that suggests the method is doing too much and you should think about splitting into the two separate parts - that would let you test them in isolation. I don't believe there's a way in RSpec to check if an attribute changes and then reverts to its default in the same block

Comment: this would work:
```it 'should have changed the status to running during execution' do
        expect(workflow).to receive(:status=).with('running').once
        expect(workflow).to receive(:status=).with('idle').once
        TriggerAction
end```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it sounds a bit like you are *testing implementation details* or should split the method a bit.

Anyway, you could dive into the features of `rspec-mocks` to achieve what you want to assert (See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts)

```rb
expect(Workflow).to receive(:running!).exactly(1).time
SomeTrigger
expect(Workflow.idle?).to be_truthy
```

(using the `attribute_changed?` methods from active_record in assertions is something I would very much **not** recommend)

EDIT: or as @DonMB [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563676/rspec-test-attribute-assignment-during-test/60564635#comment107147651_60563757) (sorry, you commented while I wrote the answer), try asserting the arguments that get sent to the attribute_accessor https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments